# DIV background images not showing on first load on Google Chrome

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, background-image, chromium

Some DIV background images not showing on first load on Google Chrome on this site:
https://ae.grupocastilla.es/epsilonnet/default.aspx

I've checked related issues, but no one gives a working answer on that case.

This is one of the controls that doesnt get the background image loaded:

> <div id="SignIn1_ImgLogin" class="ImgLogin">

Corresponding on that CSS:

> .ImgLogin
>     {
>
> > ```
> >    background-image: url(/epsilonnet/images/newlook/Login.png);
> >    background-repeat: no-repeat;
> >    background-position: center top;
> > ```
> >
> > }

- It works on FF, IE.
- It works when you refresh the page.
- It works if you put a Image element, not as background.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: It looks exactly the same on Opera, Fx and Chromium @ Ubuntu – even on first load.

Comment: I'm running Win7, I'll download Opera to check it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I'v checked it with Opera on Win7 and it's working fine.

On WinXP with Chrome, the same problem.